# Text gets highlighted if clicked with shift IE-11

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have a page with multiple tiles implementing shift-key multi-select. The problem occurring only in IE-11 is that if any text field is clicked shift-key multi-selecting, the whole browser's text gets highlighted. I have read other answers and none seem to work, including **-ms-user-select: none**, **removeAllRanges()** etc. One thing to note is that if I try and highlight a text field without pressing shift, it doesn't get highlighted ( apparently the user-select: none is working here). is there any css-only solution available then?

**Without clicking any text:**
[image]

**If any text is clicked:**

[image]

Comment: sharing some image of desired behavior might help in better understanding

Comment: How are you implementing those "tiles"? Can you post some code? Preferably a [mcve]. Normally, clicking somewhere and then shift-clicking somewhere else does select everything in between; this is normal behaviour on all browsers.

Comment: Adding the code for the tile seems unnecessary not only because it is a huge combination of react props and states, but also, I mainly want to know why the -ms-user-select fails on the text fields that have direct relation to the tiles, as shown in the screenshots.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use event.PreventDefault() not only in the *onClick()* event but also for the *mouseDown()* event. Otherwise, the text will be highlighted as long as the click isn't released.